# How I can run my first app in Apache Cordova?

Tags: cordova

I'm using the path C:/path/cordova/run.bat [Target] [Build] , the Emulator runs but I can't see the app

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with the CLI command. Open a command prompt in your project directory and:

```
cordova run <platform> <YourAppName>
```

So if you're building for Android and your app is called "helloworld":

```
cordova run android helloworld
```

Comment: Doesn't work even inside of the folder App  and with "cordova emulate android" ,"cordova compile android" .Thanks I will check my path maybe the problem is on it.